# How to delete a record in tableview with MagicalRecord CoreData in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, magicalrecord

I'm new in Swift, 
How can to delete a row of tableview with MagicalRecord in CoreData with Swift.

I have write a code like this, but don't work. how can i fix this.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle :UITableViewCellEditingStyle,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            var aCantact=contactArray[indexPath.row]
            aCantact.MR_deleteEntity()
            contactArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext().MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait()
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        switch editingStyle {
        case .Delete:
            // remove the deleted item from the model
            let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
            let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
            context.deleteObject(contactArray[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
            contactArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            context.save(nil)

            //tableView.reloadData()
            // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        default:
            return

        }
    }
```